# ng-view not rendering template view for mini SPA

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am having a hard time figuring out why the ng-view is not rendering my template html in the Asp.net MVC page.  Let me layout what I have at this point and hopefully someone can point out what I am missing.

The problem isn't the data not being generated it is the view not being rendered or data not being bound to view ... something...the data is showing as Raw json in the browser when I navigate to /KPI/Scores route.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<html ng-app="portalModule">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - CM Team Portal Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("JavascriptInHead", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("CM Team Portal", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("KPI", "Index", "KPI")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - CM Team Portal Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/portal")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Index page for my KPI SPA:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "KPI";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section JavascriptInHead
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/Scores/scores-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Scores/scores-repository.js"></script>

}

<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><span class="navbar-brand">Score Detail</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/KPI/Scores">Scores</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Here is my templates/scores.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <h2>KPI Scores</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span10">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>DrNumber</th>
                <th>ProjectName</th>
                <th>DisplayName</th>
                <th>Score</th>
                <th>DeploymentDate</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="score in scores">
                <td> {{score.drNumber}}</td>
                <td> {{score.projectName}}</td>
                <td> {{score.displayName}}</td>
                <td> {{score.score}}</td>
                <td> {{score.deploymentDate}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my BundleConfig:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Rma.ReleaseManager.Portal
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-superhero.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/portal").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/portal-module.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/angular.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my RouteConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Rma.ReleaseManager.Portal
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "KPI Scores SPA",
                url: "KPI/Scores",
                defaults: new { controller = "Scores", action = "Index" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Scores Asp.net MVC Controller:

```
    using Rma.ReleaseManager.Portal.Models.Scores;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Rma.ReleaseManager.Portal.Controllers
    {
        public class ScoresController : JsonController
        {
            // GET: Scores
            private ScoresVmBuilder _scoresVmBuilder = new ScoresVmBuilder();
            public ActionResult Index()
            {

                return Json(_scoresVmBuilder.GetScoresVM(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my JsonController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;

namespace Rma.ReleaseManager.Portal.Controllers
{
    public class JsonController : Controller
    {

        protected   new ActionResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet)
        {
            var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            if (Request.RequestType == WebRequestMethods.Http.Get && behavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("GET is not permitted for this request");

            var jsonResult = new ContentResult
            {
                Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, jsonSerializerSettings),
                ContentType = "application/json"

            };
            return jsonResult;


        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Angular Module:

```
'use strict';

var portalModule = angular.module("portalModule", ['ngResource','ngRoute'])
                .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.when('/KPI/Scores',
                        {
                            templateUrl: '/templates/scores.html',
                            controller: 'ScoresController'
                        });
                    $routeProvider.otherwise(
                        {
                            redirectTo: '/KPI/Scores'
                        });
                    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            });
```

Here is my Angular controller:

```
'use strict';

portalModule.controller("ScoresController", function ($scope, scoresRepository) {
            scoresRepository.get().then(function (scores) { $scope.scores = scores; });
        });
```

Here is my Angular repository:

```
'use strict';

portalModule.factory('scoresRepository', function ($http, $q) {
        return {
            get: function () {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('/Scores').success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where you include angular module means app.js??

Comment: I have it in my _Layout.cshtml page <html ng-app="portalModule">

Comment: where it's js located? just like you added

<script src="~/Scripts/Scores/scores-controller.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Scores/scores-repository.js"></script>

Comment: it is injected in the section just above the section you mentioned @{
    ViewBag.Title = "KPI";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: sorry it is in my BundleConfig.cs in the "~/bundles/portal"